# Solving an algebraic equation

Tags: r, yacas

I'm trying to  solve this equation: `((2300+1900*1)+(x+2300+1900*1)*0.002)/(600-400) =1`

Is there a way to do this with R?

## ATTEMPT with incorrect solution:

```
library(Ryacas)
eq <- "((2300+1900*1)+(x+2300+1900*1)*0.002)/(600-400) ==1 "
# simplify the equation:
library(glue)
yac_str(glue("Simplify({eq})"))
library(evaluate)
evaluate(eq,list(x=c(0,1,10,100,-100)))
```

`evaluate()` just returns the equation:

```
"((2300+1900*1)+(x+2300+1900*1)*0.002)/(600-400) ==1 "
```

The answer for the equation is −2004200

Comment: Do the terms `2300+1900*1` have a meaning or can they be simplified?

Comment: @RuiBarradas these terms have meaning is the rent, salary and number of workers, this equation shows what is the maximum investiment given then rent, salary and number of workers and cost of capital

Comment: Whtaat is your original equation that you want to solve? Why cant you have 200 instead of 600-400? or even 4200 instead of 2300+1900*1

Comment: 600 is the price of the product 400 is the unitary cost, I am developing a general function to show the maximum investment given price, unit cost, fixed costs, cost of capital and 1 sale per period

Comment: And what is 0.002?

Comment: 0.002 is the cost of capital per month in my country, opportunity cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R solution.
Rewrite the equation in the form of a function, use `curve` to get two end points where the function has different signs and put `uniroot` to work.

```
f <- function(x) ((2300+1900*1)+(x+2300+1900*1)*0.002)/(600-400) - 1
curve(f, -1e7, 1)
uniroot(f, c(-1e7, 1))
#$root
#[1] -2004200
#
#$f.root
#[1] 0
#
#$iter
#[1] 1
#
#$init.it
#[1] NA
#
#$estim.prec
#[1] 7995800
```

---

Following the discussion in the comments to the question, here is a general solution. The function whose roots are to be found now accepts an argument `params` in order to pass the values of rent, salary, number of workers, price, unit cost and capital cost. This argument must be a named list.

```
f <- function(x, K = 1, params) {
  A <- with(params, rent + salary*workers)
  with(params, (A + (x + A)*capitalcost)/(price - unitcost) - K)
}

params <- list(
  rent = 2300, 
  salary = 1900, 
  workers = 1, 
  price = 600, 
  unitcost = 400, 
  capitalcost = 0.002
)
curve(f(x, params = params), -1e7, 1)
uniroot(f, c(-1e7, 1), params = params)
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to `Solve()` for x rather than merely simplifying ... ? The following code solves the equation, strips off the `x==` from the solution, and evaluates the expression:

```r
eq2 <- gsub("x==","",yac_str(glue("Solve({eq},x)")))
[1] "{(-0.80168e6)/0.4}"
eval(parse(text=eq2))
[1] -2004200
```

Answer (score 2):

**1) Ryacas** Use the `Ryacas` package `solve` as shown below. (Thanks to @mikldk for improvement to last line.)

```
library(Ryacas)
eq <- "((2300+1900*1)+(x+2300+1900*1)*0.002)/(600-400) ==1 "  # from question

res <- solve(ysym(eq), "x")
as_r(y_rmvars(res))  # extract and convert to R
## [1] -2004200
```

if `eq` has R variables in it, here `h` is referenced in `eq2`, then use `eval` to evaluate the result.

```
h <- 2300
eq2 <- "((h+1900*1)+(x+2300+1900*1)*0.002)/(600-400) ==1 "  # from question
res2 <- solve(ysym(eq2), "x")
eval(as_r(y_rmvars(res2)))
## [1] -2004200
```

**2) Ryacas0** or using `eq` from above with the `Ryacas0` package:

```
library(Ryacas0)

res <- Solve(eq, "x")
eval(Expr(res)[[1:3]]) # convert to R
## [1] -2004200
```

**3a) Base R** In light of the fact that this is a linear equation and the solution to the following where A is the slope and B is the intercept:

```
A * x + B = 0
```

is

```
x = - B / A
```

if we replace `x` with the imaginary `1i` and then move the rhs to the lhs we have that `B` and `A` are the real and imaginary parts of that expression.  No packages are used.

```
r <- eval(parse(text = sub("==", "-", eq)), list(x = 1i))
-Re(r) / Im(r)
## [1] -2004200
```

**3b)** If we move the rhs to lhs then B equals it at x=0 and A equals the derivative wrt x so another base R solution would be:

```
e <- parse(text = sub("==", "-", eq))
- eval(e, list(x = 0)) / eval(D(e, "x"))
## [1] -200420
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want something quick: `rootSolve` library is your go-to.

```py
library(rootSolve)
func_ <- function(x) ((2300+1900*1)+(x+2300+1900*1)*0.002)/(600-400)-1
uniroot.all(func_, c(-1e9, 1e9))
[1] -2004200
```

Note that most of the time reducing the interval is better.

Answer (score 0):

If you will maintain the same structure, then in Base R, you could do:

```
solveX <- function(eq){
  U <- function(x)abs(eval(parse(text = sub("=+","-", eq)), list(x=x)))
  optim(0, U, method = "L-BFGS-B")$par
}
eq <- "((2300+1900*1)+(x+2300+1900*1)*0.002)/(600-400) ==1 "
solveX(eq)
[1] -2004200
```